# Creating Custom Header and passing credentials?

Tags: angularjs

I am a novice to angular.js and I am trying to add a custom header to a request.

I have a function through which i have to get a response from the service

```
function getInsuredWebAccount(insuredId) {

        };
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var related = $resource(webAccountServiceHostName + '/user/v1/account/:insuredId');
        related.get({ insuredId: insuredId }, function onSuccess(response) {

            var webInfo = response.results;
            deferred.resolve(response);

        }, function onFailure(response) {
            deferred.reject(response);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

I have to pass `("Authorization", "Bearer c3J1bml0ZTo1OUJFODUwNUIyRjM0OEVGQTI1RTU1RjU4NEVGNUE0")` in the header.

Can some one guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the headers in your resource constructor:

```
var related = $resource(webAccountServiceHostName + '/user/v1/account/:insuredId', {}, {
    get: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer c3J1bml0ZTo1OUJFODUwNUIyRjM0OEVGQTI1RTU1RjU4NEVGNUE0"
        }
    }
});
```